# spring authentication md5

Tags: java, spring, md5

Every time I try to connect I found the password(md5) change in my db(mysql)
so I can't authenticated.

```
@Entity
public class UserEntity extends BaseEntity  {


    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8789920463809744548L;
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }
    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }
    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }
    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {

         PasswordEncoder crypto = new Md5PasswordEncoder();
        this.password = crypto.encodePassword(password, null);
      //  System.out.println(this.password);
        //this.password=password;
    }   

}
```

---

```
 <security:authentication-manager >
            <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="userServices">
                 <security:password-encoder hash="md5" /> 
            </security:authentication-provider>
 </security:authentication-manager>
```

Comment: Because that is what you are doing yourself in the `setPassword` method...

Comment: i didn't understand can you explain ?? plz

Comment: Your set password method is encrypting it again... and again...

Comment: when i try to take this two line it wok but the password don't encrypted    PasswordEncoder crypto = new Md5PasswordEncoder();
        this.password = crypto.encodePassword(password, null);

Comment: can someone here help plz

Comment: Don't encrypt the password in the `setPassword` method, you need to encrypt it before you set it. If you don't Spring Security in turn will (when loading the user) MD5 the already Md5 hashed password, upon which you will never be able to login.

Comment: You really, really, really shouldn't be using MD5 to store passwords. It's not a secure hashing algorithm anymore AND you're not using a salt. [For common passwords just googling the hash will most likely yield the right clear text password](https://www.google.de/search?q=5f4dcc3b5aa765d61d8327deb882cf99). You can just use [BCryptPasswordEncoder](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.3.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/crypto/bcrypt/BCryptPasswordEncoder.html) instead which is actually secure and requires minimal changes.